# Inline-block element drops to second line when padding is applied

Tags: html, css, list, line

As the title states, the inline-block list item element drops to the second line. How would I go about keeping them all both centered and on the same line? Thanks!
Below I've posted the full css code along with an image.

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

nav .container {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav .container ul {
    margin: 0;
}

nav .container ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav .container ul li:nth-child(1n+2) {
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUQ68.jpg)

Comment: If you can add your code here http://jsfiddle.net/ and then it will be easier to help you

Comment: Sure. JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rj0z650t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is not clear feel free to ask me.

```
nav .container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Don't know but the underline bugs me a lot with a black background. If you want to remove it add this to the css. (but you probably know that)

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This one is not centered!

Comment: Your face is not centered.

Comment: I understand that, thank you so much. Yes, it seems it is a little off centered, weird.

Comment: @DeanHampson anytime man, if you need more examples on how to make a better looking navigation, just find a made one already, you might learn something new from them. http://www.html5xcss3.com/p/horizontal-css3-menus-tutorials.html

Comment: Also if my answer helped, don't forget to mark it as answered, it will help for someone else with the same problem (and some points for me ;d )

Comment: Cheers. Where can I find the option to give points? Been searching for a while!

Comment: It's enough to check it as an answer. You've done that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make few CSS changes to get it. Please try below CSS, it works

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
}


nav .container ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

nav .container ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

nav .container ul li:nth-child(1n+2) {
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```